# When did members of the Justice League pull the Earth with Wonder Woman's lasso?

Tags: dc, comics, episode-identification, justice-league

I saw a page where the Justice League members are trying to move the earth away from its orbit using Wonder Woman's lasso.

Which comic is this from?

Comment: Googling the title gives you the picture, googling the picture gives you the issue number. Downvoted for lack of research effort.

Answer (score 5):

I'm almost certain the panel below is the one you're looking for, but I can't seem to find what comic it was from.

[image: Martian Manhunter, Wonder Woman and Superman pull Earth]

Comment: It's [JLA Vol 1 #75](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/JLA_Vol_1_75). I've added the link to the dupe.

Comment: Oh there's a dupe, my bad

Comment: In fairness the dupe didn't have the issue number in it until a few moments ago.